# Characterization of continuous flows on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I'm struggling with the proof of the following result:

*Proposition*

Let $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$. A mapping $\phi: \mathbb{R} \times (a,b) \rightarrow (a,b)$ defines a continuous flow if there exists a finite or countable set of disjoint intervals $(a_n,b_n) \subset (a,b)$, $ \left( n \in J \right)$  and for every $n \in J$ there exists an homomorphism $r_n$ from $(a_n,b_n)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ such that,

$$
\phi(t,x) = 
\begin{cases}
x , \; &\text{if} \; x \notin \cup_{n \in J} (a_n,b_n) \\
r_n^{-1}(r_n(x)+t) , \;  &\text{if} \; x \in (a_n,b_n), \, n \in J
\end{cases}
$$
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

The proof goes as follows. The set $K := \{x \in (a,b): \phi(t,x) = x, \; \;\forall t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is closed in $(a,b)$, so $(a,b)\setminus K$ is open and is the union of a finite or countable set of disjoint intervals $(a_n,b_n)$,  $n \in J$. Take $x_n \in (a_n,b_n)$ and define $\alpha_n(t) := \phi(t,x_n)$. This is an injective mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ into $(a_n,b_n)$.

**Question:**
Why are those maps injective?

I have tried the following. Take $t_2 > t_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha_n(t_1) = \alpha_n(t_2)$. Therefore, as $t_2 = t_1 + \tau$ for some $\tau >0$ we have that
$$
\phi(t_1,x_n) = \phi(\tau,\phi(t_1,x_n)),
$$
so $y_n := \phi(t_1,x_n) \in (a_n,b_n)$ verifies that $y_n = \phi(\tau,y_n)$. Then my idea is to use this new point to find a contradiction with the fact that $y_n \notin K$. But so far I haven't been able to do it.

Any suggestions?